# как удалить повторяющиеся элементы в структуре Go

Tags: golang, golang-struct

есть структура

```
type Users struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Surname     string `json:"surname"`
}
```

в нее записаны элементы которые могут полностью повторяться и Name и Surname, то есть
Иван Иванов и еще один Иван Иванов

как удалить из структуры такие дубли?

Comment: А в golang есть словари/map/set?

Comment: вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706801/deduplicate-array-of-structs

Comment: Удалить только повторные значения (второе и последующее вхождения)?  Или удалить элементы, у которых есть повторные значения (частота которых больше 1)?

Comment: В этой структуре возможно только одно значение в Name и Surname, как они могут повторяться?